# Elastic Search with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, lucene

I am working on writing migrating JAVA based REST API from ES 2.4.x version to ES 6.4.x with Spring Boot 3.1.0 targeting minimal changes.

The ES 2.4.x had a different way of indexing data where one index contain many types and thus the Mapping class/ES Bean class had something like :-

@Document(indexName = INDEX_HOUSEHOLD_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT, type = TYPE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT)

Now that we need to create separate indexes for each type (this is what i understood from ES support sites) , How will the above be managed ? Will the indexName and typeName be same in both this case for Mapping class?

Answer (score 0):

In ES 6.4.x you are limited to one type per index. You can have the index name be the same as your type name, but you don't need to. I've heard in ES 7.x that they are moving towards just have the type be `_doc`.

Comment: Yes, but how will this look like for the mapping class in Spring boot configuration. DO we type in the same name for index and type  in the mapping class as well ? Will that work or has spring boot implemented something else?